# How can I split this string in two parts using a regex?

Tags: python, regex

Imagine this:

```
a = "('a','b','c'),('d','e','f')"
```

I am trying to split it using re so that I will get an array of 2 elements, containing `"('a','b','c')"` and `('d','e','f')`. I tried :

```
matches = re.split("(?:\)),(?:\()",a)
```

but this gives me the result:

```
'(2,3,4'
'1,6,7)'
```

I could parse it, character by character, but if a regex solution is possible, I would prefer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split on the comma which is preceded by a `)` and followed by a `(`. But the parenthesis themselves should not be part of the split point. For that you need to use positive lookahead and positive look behind assertions as:

```
matches = re.split("(?<=\)),(?=\()",a)
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/uefiH)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = "('a','b','c'),('d','e','f')"
x, y = literal_eval(a)
```

After this, `x` will be `('a', 'b', 'c')` which can be stringized with `str(x)`, or, if spaces matter,

```
"(%s)" % ",".join(repr(z) for z in x)
```

Answer (score 2):

`split` is the wrong tool here. You want `findall`:

```
import re
a = "('a','b','c'),('d','e','f')"
matches = re.findall("\([^)]*\)", a)
```

or pretty much equivalently,

```
matches = re.findall("\(.*?\)", a)
```

Comment: +1 like this one, is way simpler, but this would be even better: `re.findall("\([^()]*\)", s)`: you want anything that isn't `(` or `)`.

Comment: Well, another opening brace doesn't really hurt any - you just need to disallow the closing one so the greedy star knows where to stop. Opening parentheses pose no problem whatsoever. To be sure, this method breaks down if you have any quoted closing parentheses inside the strings, but handling that properly with just regexp rather than a parser just does not work. It also does not check whether or not you have commas between the parenthesised items.

Comment: your answer is 100% accurate for the OP's question. My comment was just a improvment, to make it work in other scenarios. For instance, if he had: `s = '((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))'`, your solution will give us: `['((1, 2, 3)', '(4, 5, 6)']` (nothe the extra opening brace), while with my modification, `matches` would be: `['(1, 2, 3)', '(4, 5, 6)']`